# Ubuntu 17.04 package updates

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, update-manager, repository

Every time when I run the `sudo apt-get update` command I get these errors:

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/next/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/next/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Can anyone please help me in that?

Comment: That usually means there are no packages for this Ubuntu release. Indeed, [the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix/+archive/ubuntu/next) was last updated 141 week ago, and the latest packages are for 14.10. Run `sudo ppa-purge ppa:tualatrix/next` to remove it.

Comment: Tried the said command, but it still gives me the same errors that I mentioned.

Comment: You must update the package catalog. Run `sudo apt-get update` after removing the repository..

Comment: Restarted the system after running the ppa-purge cmd, it still gives me the mentioned errors when I run apt-get update .